# Any way to tell that computer is running low in memory in Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, caching, memory, ram

I know of System.totalMemory and privateMemory and freeMemory. But these say nothing whether the host computer is capable of loading another 100MBs of data. I need to know if it can - before crashing - so that I may decide whether to "cache" more data into the RAM or not.

Any way to tackle this?

**EDIT** : The data are 3D meshes (skinned with animations, materials etc). The user can add in his "scene" as many as he likes. I would like to be able to tell "stop" when low in memory and before a crash occurs.

Comment: `System.freeMemory` gives you "the amount of memory (in bytes) that is allocated to Adobe® Flash® Player or Adobe® AIR® and that is not in use", in other words, the memory which still available for your application, but don't forget that loading 100MBs of data may need more than 100MBs of memory ...

Comment: @akmozo Wait, freeMemory means "that's as much as you'll get"? Isn't it supposed to automatically increase if there is a demand for it? (which could cause an increase in Virtual Memory needed...etc etc... crash). In fact, the docs say: "Use this property to monitor garbage collection" - NOT to find if there's enough RAM available. Maybe I misinterpreted it?

Comment: It's the free memory of the total currently allocated memory. And yes, I think that Flash Player / AIR will request any needed memory from the OS until its crash (the Flash Player / AIR) ...

Comment: @akmozo Like I thought. So this won't help. I assume there is NO way to do what I want...

Comment: this is not correct, memory is allocated as you need it on all system. What you have no control over is the type of memory you'll get. Ideally this is RAM but if the system decides you take too much of it it will give you hard drive space instead and in that case your app will start to slow down. Cases of crashes when requesting system memory are rare or even nonexistent for that reason. Graphic card memory works differently and is truly limited and can produce crashes.

Comment: @BillKotsias, what type of data is this 100mb? Is it video / audio streams? if not then at least is the data container itself not re-cycleable meaning load 100mb, use as needed, and then clear buffer to get the next 100mb etc?

Comment: @VC.One Check my updated question. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm... You're gunna have to do some calculations. I would check the freeMemory and measure ram usage against a test mesh size (total faces). 100 faces vs 200 faces vs 1000 faces etc. This will give an idea of how much each mesh will use in ram. Are you able to get the "total faces" info (from mesh file metadata? Dunno what format you have or what system you're using to parse the meshes in AS3).